# Ad overlay requires the useClientJar flag in intent extras.

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

Ran into this issue trying to get Interstitial Ads to work on my first android app. Being a complete novice I really had on idea how to add the "useClientJar" flag to the Intent Extras.

This wasn't the issue, it's actually an error in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and I'm posting this question/answer because it's one of the few situations I've run into with only 5 relevant google results, the top one being a piece of IRC chat with one poor guy running into the same problem as me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that I had foolishly made my main activity into the AdActivity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" <!-- notice this name, this means the interstitial ad is now the main activity! -->
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

The fix of course was to correct this like so:

```
<!-- They are now two separate activities -->
<activity
            android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```